# onBeforeUnload being applied whole application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

im using a service that basically popups a box when a user tries to refresh or close the page, and it works fine, but basically i just want to be apply in a specific page, but the problem is that being applied in the rest of the pages.

I tried applying inside of a if statement that includes a specifc state location, but still is being applied in the rest of the app.

Service:

```
angular.module('farm')
    .factory('beforeUnload', function ($rootScope, $window) {
        // Events are broadcast outside the Scope Lifecycle

        $window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            var confirmation = {};
            var event = $rootScope.$broadcast('onBeforeUnload', confirmation);
            if (event.defaultPrevented) {
                return confirmation.message;
            }
        };

        $window.onunload = function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('onUnload');
        };
        return {};
    })
    .run(function (beforeUnload) {
        // Must invoke the service at least once
    });
```

Controller:

```
 if ($state.includes("app.cal.lab.result")){
                $scope.$on('onBeforeUnload', function (e, confirmation) {
                    confirmation.message = "All data willl be lost.";
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                $scope.$on('onUnload', function (e) {
                    console.log('leaving page'); // Use 'Preserve Log' option in Console
                });
            }
```

Comment: Just check current path with `$location` or `$state` if using ui-router. No need for angular event